# Dynamic Data table with <canvas>

Tags: jquery, html, css, canvas

I need some help figuring out displaying dynamic data with canvas.
Check out the life code is here https://jsfiddle.net/fbteabu8/

HTML

```
<div class="data-square-percentage-2" data-type="square-percentage" data-id="percentage-2" data-value="50">
  <div class="label"></div>
  <canvas></canvas>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
  font-family: 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
}

.data-square-percentage,
.data-square-percentage-2
{
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 10px 20px 0;
  background: #EEE;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

.label {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
}
```

JS

```
$('[data-type="square-percentage"]').each(function() {
    var pdata = {
      width: $(this).width(),
      height: $(this).height(),
      canvas: $(this).children('canvas'),
      percentWidth: $(this).width() / 10,
      percentHeight: $(this).height() / 10,
      elID: $(this).data('id'),
      percent: $(this).data('value')
    }

   $(this).children('.label').text(pdata.percent + '%');
    pdata.canvas.attr({
      'width': pdata.width,
      'height': pdata.height,
      'id': pdata.elID
    });

    pdata.ctx = document.getElementById(pdata.elID).getContext("2d");
    pdata.ctx.beginPath();
    pdata.ctx.fillStyle = "#ff008d";
    pdata.ctx.strokeStyle = "#ffdbef";
    pdata.ctx.globalAlpha = 1;


    for (i = 0, k = 0, r = 0; i < pdata.percent; i++, k++) {
      if (k > 9) k = 0, r++;
      pdata.ctx.restore();
      pdata.ctx.rect((pdata.percentWidth * k), (pdata.percentHeight * r), pdata.percentWidth, pdata.percentHeight);
      pdata.ctx.fill();
      pdata.ctx.stroke();
      pdata.ctx.save();
    }
  });
});
```

My question is: I've been able to populate the data tables correctly, but now I need to split the second table into more data points. So, for example, instead of coloring pink 46% out of a 100% I want it to be able to split into 4 percentage amounts with different colors. Sort of like so:

[Data Display Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axFHq.png)

Let me know if it doesn't make sense or if you have a better solution of avoiding canvas and using something else, like SVG animation, etc.

Thank you in advance!